# How to prevent people from dropping in non-droppable elements?

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am implementing drag and drop this way.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('modernizr/2.5.3/modernizr.min.js', array('block' => 'scriptTop')); ?>


$(document).ready(function () {
    dropArea = document.getElementById("droparea");

    dropArea.addEventListener("dragleave", function (evt) {
        var target = evt.target;

        if (target && target === dropArea) {
            this.className = "";
        }

        dropArea.className = "";
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();

    }, false);

    dropArea.addEventListener("dragenter", function (evt) {
        this.className = "over";
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();

    }, false);

    dropArea.addEventListener("dragover", function (evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();

    }, false);
    // this is the initial add-drop
    dropArea.addEventListener("drop", function (evt) {
        doStuff();
        this.className = "";
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();

    }, false);
  }
```

There are times when my users dropped stuff NOT into `#droparea`.

I want to prevent them from doing that.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a noop `dragover` and `drop` handler for your document.  This will prevent the default browser behavior of replacing current page with dropped file.

[See here for a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nonplus/AC6w4/)

```
// Handle dropping on non-droparea    
document.addEventListener("drop", cancelEvent, false);
document.addEventListener("dragover", cancelEvent, false);

function cancelEvent(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restrict the drop area so that it can be dropped to only required one.

Update the drop event handler as :

```
dropArea.addEventListener("drop",function(evt){
//default cancel
    evt.preventDefault();
    evt.stopPropagation();
},true);
```

**Note:** parameter "true" is applied.

Refer to the [link](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/03/implementing-drag-and-drop-functions-with-html5-and-javascript/) for more details.

You may refer to demo [here](http://www.developerdrive.com/demo/html_dragndrop/demo.html)

Comment: I am doing drop an image into the droparea. I think the demo is different from my use case

Comment: But, it restricts the dropping in other area.

Comment: I cannot find the actual code that indicates the restricting of the dropping. Can enlighten?

Comment: In each div, the handler ondragover="event.preventDefault();" prevents dragging over it. And in image the handlers does this thing as <img src="pic1.jpg" width="80" height="80" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragIt(event);" id="pic1" />

Comment: What about the rest of the html document? In my situation, I have a single div called droparea where I *allow* users to drag and drop images into it. However, they sometimes accidentally drop their images *outside* this droparea and they get confused. This is what I want to prevent. As you can see from my question, I asked "There are times when my users dropped stuff NOT into #droparea.

I want to prevent them from doing that."

Comment: Refer to link : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/ for more details and demos. I think this will be more helpful to customize your application.

Comment: Here is the fiddle for simple image drag and drop http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/8GGUv/

Comment: You need to do some cosmetic changes in your drop event handler, please find the updates in above answer.                                You can refer to related demo at http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/R79Fs/1/

Comment: Sorry was busy the past 2 days. Let me go check.

Comment: Didn't work. Put in the stopPropagation and preventDefault and the true as well. You can trigger the same error using the demo link you supplied. Drag an image into the webpage anywhere and you will suddenly see the image show up.

Comment: Try to add return false instead of stopPropagation and preventDefault

Comment: Thanks, but I found my solution